# TableLayoutPanel GetControlFromPosition does not get non-visible controls. How do you access a non-visible control at a specified position?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm using a `TableLayoutPanel` and I want to get the control at a specific position in the `TableLayoutPanel`. I want to iterate over the rows and columns of `TableLayoutPanel` but this question applies equally if I just wanted a single control at a specific row and column.
Unfortunately `GetControlFromPosition(int column, int row)` only retrieves controls that are visible (that is their Visible property is set to True). This is no good to me as sometimes I want to access a control at a specific position that is not visible and then make it visible.

I have had to resort to iterating over the `TableLayoutPanel.Controls` collection, and then get the position of each control using `GetPositionFromControl(Control control)` or `GetCellPosition(Control control)` until I find the position I want.
(I'm not sure of the difference between `GetPositionFromControl` and `GetCellPosition` methods as MS documentation is meagre, but [I'll ask that question separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142220/tablelayoutpanel-getcellposition-and-getpositionfromcontrol-how-do-they-differ)).

Is there a simpler or cleaner way for me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can come up with is creating an extension method.  Create a new module named "Extensions.vb" and add:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetAnyControlAt(Panel As TableLayoutPanel, Column As Integer, Row As Integer) As Control
        For Each PanelControl As Control In Panel.Controls
            With Panel.GetCellPosition(PanelControl)
                If Column = .Column AndAlso Row = .Row Then Return PanelControl
            End With
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you can use the following to access the method:

```vb
Dim MyControl As Control = TableLayoutPanel1.GetAnyControlAt(Column, Row)
```

Extension methods add the method to the class that's listed as the first parameter, in this case `Panel As TableLayoutPanel`, and shuffle the rest of the parameters along.

Comment: And what I love about Stack Overflow is that I didn't take the time to learn about extension methods until you gave me a reason to.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've been extending classes or using helper methods, or partial classes until now. Extension methods could be more useful or simpler to implement. Did you use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx as a reference for learning?

Answer (score 3):

better c# method:

```
public static Control GetAnyControlAt(this TableLayoutPanel panel, int column, int row)
{
    foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)
    {
        var cellPosition = panel.GetCellPosition(control);
        if (cellPosition.Column == column && cellPosition.Row == row)
            return control;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And for c#:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
        {
            public static Control GetAnyControlAt(TableLayoutPanel pp, int col, int row)
            {
            bool fnd = false;
            Control sendCC = null;
            foreach (Control cc in pp.Controls)
            {
                if (pp.GetCellPosition(cc).Column == col)
                {
                    if (pp.GetCellPosition(cc).Row == row)
                    {
                        sendCC = cc;
                        fnd = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (fnd == true)
            {
                return sendCC;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround/hack to use GetControlFromPosition for visible=false, first add the control to the table layout panel and then set visible to false

example:

```
CheckBox Chk_Tbl_exist = new CheckBox();
Chk_Tbl_exist.Text = "This is a checkbox"; 
TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(Chk_Tbl_exist, 0, 1);
Chk_Tbl_exist.Visible = false;
```