# TableLayoutPanel GetCellPosition and GetPositionFromControl, how do they differ?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

This may seem a trite question but I find the Microsoft documentation on these methods lacking in any detail.

What is the difference between [`TablelLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(Control control)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcellposition.aspx) and [`TableLayoutPanel.GetPositionFromControl(Control control)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getpositionfromcontrol.aspx) ?

I'm using .NET Framework 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetCellPosition` gets the declared position of the control, where as `GetPositionFromControl` gets the actual position the `TableLayoutPanel` has decided for the control.  These are the same in most cases.  Programatically set several controls to the same cell (or overlapping cells with `ColumnSpan` or `RowSpan`,) and see how the results differ.

Add a TableLayoutPanel to a Form and copy the following code.  Run it and click on a Label to see the difference.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Index As Integer = 0 To 4
            Dim Control As New Label
            Control.Text = String.Format("Control {0}", Index)
            AddHandler Control.Click, AddressOf Control_Click
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Control, 0, 0)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Control_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim Pos1 As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = TableLayoutPanel1.GetPositionFromControl(sender)
        Dim Pos2 As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = TableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(sender)
        Dim Text As String = String.Format("GetPositionFromControl = {0},{1}" & vbCrLf & "GetCellPosition = {2},{3}", Pos1.Column, Pos1.Row, Pos2.Column, Pos2.Row)
        MessageBox.Show(Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using `GetCellPosition`, for which the Microsoft documentation is lacking. At least the `GetPositionFromControl` documentation does explain it somewhat. Thanks for rounding out the meaning for me. The [LayoutEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.layoutengine.aspx) documentation, linked from `GetPositionFromControl` documentation tells me very little as well.

Comment: One caveat that is not mentioned in the `GetPositionFromControl` documentation is that it returns -1 for the `Row` and `Column` properties of the returned `TableLayoutPanelCellPosition` if the `Control` parameter you pass to `GetPositionFromControl` has its `Visible` property set to `False`. Thus you need to use `GetCellPosition` if you want the position of non-visible controls (Bearing in mind the caveats for `GetCellPosition` mentioned in this answer).