# How to get the Cell Position of a TableLayoutPanel for a radioButton

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

Here is my code, it is returning (-1, -1) as the coordinates of the cell position. Which I assume means the control was not found in the table. My radio buttons are sitting inside a panel within the table cell. However, radio.Container returns null.

```
private void radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radio = sender as RadioButton;
    var coord = tblPanel.GetPositionFromControl(radio);//returns (-1, -1)
}
```

I would like to get the row number from the sender object by any means necessary. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Daniel

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcolumn.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getrow.aspx state  _"The row/column position of control, or -1 if the position of control is determined by LayoutEngine."_

Comment: The quote refers to "GetColumn". The second link you provided says: "To get the actual position of control, even when its position is determined by LayoutEngine, call the GetPositionFromControl method."

Comment: No I wasnt confused about the link not helping, I am just confused on the documentation itself which to me is just unclear, at first it seemed like it was saying `GetPositionFromControl` is the same as getColumn and getRow...  Maybe this is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142220/tablelayoutpanel-getcellposition-and-getpositionfromcontrol-how-do-they-differ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out what I needed was the parent property which in this case was the panel. Container was always null.

```
private void radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var radio = sender as RadioButton;
        var row = tblPanel.GetRow(radio.Parent);
}
```