# How to get acces the spesific controls(textbox, combobox..) on tableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get acces the spesific controls(textbox, combobox..) on tableLayoutPanel?

I tryed by these codes:

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tblIsyeri.RowCount; i++)
    {
        if (tblIsyeri.GetControlFromPosition(1, i).GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
        {
            ComboBox cmb = tblIsyeri.GetControlFromPosition(1, i);
            cmb.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(OrtakSinif.veriArray[i + 1].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            tblIsyeri.GetControlFromPosition(1, i).Text = OrtakSinif.veriArray[i + 1].ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

take an eror on this line:

```
ComboBox cmb = tblIsyeri.GetControlFromPosition(1, i);
```

> "Compiler Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Windows.Forms.Control to Combobox . An explicit converion exist(Are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Please specify what error is thrown. Also, have you tried using alternatives like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142138/tablelayoutpanel-getcontrolfromposition-does-not-get-non-visible-controls-how-d

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. If you post the **Error CS0266** message and read it carefully it will tell you half of the solution to your problem. Please post it and we will help you to understand it.

Comment: Just cast it: `ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox) tblIsyeri.GetControlFromPosition(1, i);`

Comment: so you answer is in the last part of the error message: "An explicit converion exist(Are you missing a cast?)"" Yes you are missing a cast. `GetControlFromPosition` returns a `Control` which is a parent class of `ComboBox`. But you need the child. Depending on your C# version you could actually check and cast the type in one line: `if (tblIsyeri.GetControlFromPosition(1, i) is ComboBox cmb)` and then use the `cmb` variable inside the if clause.

Comment: i found the solution: **'ComboBox comboBox = tblIsyeri.GetControlFromPosition(1, i) as ComboBox;'**  thank you.

Comment: off topic: it is a bad habbit to have empty catch clauses. At least log the exception or write it to the output window using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`